# Connecting client and server on different networks using TCP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I'm trying to connect a client to a server on different networks (over Internet), client on my friend's pc and server on mine using TCP but i get invalid ip in client.
the IP is hardcoded just to test the connection and the ability to send something.

Client code:

```
class Client
{
    Socket clientSocket;
    byte[] buffer;

    public Client()
    {
        initializeClient();
    }

    private void initializeClient()
    {
        clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hi server, i am a client");
        clientSocket.Connect(new IPAddress(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("156.205.***.**")), 100);
        //***.** altered by me to protect my IP but the ip is written complete in the code
        clientSocket.Send(buffer);
        clientSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
class Server
{
    static byte[] buffer;
    static Socket serverSocket;
    static List<Socket> clientSockets;

    private void initializeServer()
    {
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
        serverSocket.Listen(5);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket newClient = serverSocket.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("new Client accepted: "+ newClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(AcceptClients));
            newThread.Start(newClient);
        }
    }

    public Server()
    {
        initializeServer();
    }

    private void AcceptClients(object obj)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)obj;
        clientSockets.Add(client);
        int recevied = client.Receive(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("client said: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, recevied));
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but i get invalid ip in client"_ - please read [ask] and post the actual exception message including your research. Chances are that you didn't forward the appropriate port. How to do port forwarding is well documented on the web.

Comment: @CodeCaster i did port forwarding by making my ip static then adding the port 100 to my router virtual servers but still i get the same error: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: An invalid IP address was specified.
Parameter name: address
   at System.Net.IPAddress..ctor(Byte[] address)

Comment: Oh, yeah, `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("156.205.***.**")` isn't gonna work. You either need `new byte[] { 156, 205, ...}` or simply call `IPAddress.Parse("156.205....")`.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah that fixed it :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("156.205.***.**") was wrong. it worked with new byte[] { 156, 205, ...}